# DjangoUnicodeDecodeError at /accounts/login/

Tags: django, unicode, ascii

Всем доброго дня!

Развернул django-проект на **ubuntu (nginx + uwsgi)**. 

При попытке залогиниться с вводом неверного пароля срабатывает исключение кодировки.
[image: скрин]

Traceback:

```
Django Version: 1.9.7
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'person',
 'person_true',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'list_client',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'bootstrap3']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bootstrap3/templates/bootstrap3/form_errors.html, error at line 4
   ascii   1 : 
   2 : <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable alert-link">
   3 :     <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&#215;</button>
   4 :      {% for error in errors %} 
   5 :         {{ error }}{% if not forloop.last %}<br>{% endif %}
   6 :     {% endfor %}
   7 : </div>
   8 : 

Traceback:

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  174.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  172.                     response = response.render()

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  160.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  137.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  206.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/library.py" in render
  201.         output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bootstrap3/templatetags/bootstrap3.py" in bootstrap_form
  324.     return render_form(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bootstrap3/forms.py" in render_form
  46.     return renderer_cls(form, **kwargs).render()

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bootstrap3/renderers.py" in render
  72.         return mark_safe(self._render())

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bootstrap3/renderers.py" in _render
  209.         return self.render_errors() + self.render_fields()

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bootstrap3/renderers.py" in render_errors
  202.                     'layout': self.layout,

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bootstrap3/utils.py" in render_template_file
  149.     return template.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  206.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  179.             for i, item in enumerate(values):

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py" in __iter__
  581.                 v = self[i]

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/utils.py" in __getitem__
  146.             return list(error)[0]

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/exceptions.py" in __iter__
  165.                 yield force_text(message)

File "/home/nexx/ENV/black_list/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
  88.             raise DjangoUnicodeDecodeError(s, *e.args)

Exception Type: DjangoUnicodeDecodeError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f3b5c163b50> (<class 'django.utils.functional.__proxy__'>)
```

Буду рад любому совету!

Answer (score 0):

**Решено!**

Неведомо как, но после многочисленных манипуляций заработало.

Возможно, помогло это:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```